# Error caused when converting android activity based app to fragment based

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to Android Development and I have a simple list app which I have been asked to create.I have had no problems having the app as activity based however I have to extend the functionality and use fragments for a 'universal' app.  My main activity is:

Comment: One of your fragments are wrongly configured, can you paste the code for the fragment itself? Does it has a default constructor.

Comment: Update - Fragment code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to successfully compile your code by taking the following steps:

It looks like this line is the problem (inside Main.java):

```
contactCursor = contactDBAdapter.getAllContactsCursor();
```

I looked at how your `contactDBAdapter` gets initialized and it turns out you initialize it after you `setContentView` for your activity. However, your view involves calls to `contactDBAdapter`. So in Main.java you need to move the following two lines to the TOP of the onCreate window:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    contactDBAdapter = new ContactDBAdapter(this);
    contactDBAdapter.open();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ....
}
```

Furthermore, the following line in Main.java needs to be removed (or commented out):

```
contact.clear();
```

Also, I had to make two further changes to how you call ListView

1. In list_view.xml, the way you identify a ListView for Android is :

   android:id="@+id/android:list"
2. In ContactListFragment.java, then call the ListView this way :

   parent.myListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

Comment: What calls to the fragment are you referring to?

Comment: Pardon, I see what you're doing. Do you mind posting your R.layout.list_view?

Comment: Can you try to redo your id in list_view to the same format: android:id="@android:id/list"? I described with an example above...

Comment: Get an error in ContactListFragment - list cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: Could you post more of your logcat? I pasted your project into Eclipse (and made up dummy files for the ones I didn't have) but I'm getting the views to expand correctly. As a side note, this may not solve your problem, but sometimes deleting the problematic xml file and retyping it seems to be the cure.

Comment: Attached logcat - I can mail you my actual files if that would help? Really appreciate your help, as have been stuck with this for weeks!Have already tried creating new xml files

Comment: I updated my response above. Also, I'm not sure how to get the files without exposing my email address to the world. You could just post the few remaining files above in addition to ContactDBAdapter?

Comment: Just for completeness could you include your layout for addcontact? And info.xml.

Comment: what does R.id.add refer to? From ContactListFragment.java, line 68

Comment: Is there an associated xml for that?

Comment: sorry just realised thats refering to an id of a context menu that I had forgot to include xml of context menu -  see new update

Comment: I don't see the xml for the menu? Also: I've edited my comments above.

Comment: Its the very last update in my question. How would you reccommend resolving this null pointer exception?

Comment: Thank you very much! Much appreciated! One last thing since you are familiar with my code - when I click on a contact their details should show in the info fragment - in landscape mode nothing happens and generates a null pointer exception at 149 in main. In portrait mode it creates the new intent but doesnt pass the information. Thanks again

Comment: You have to enable the menu inside your fragment. Add the line 'setHasOptionsMenu(true);' to the onCreateView inside ContactListFragment.java.  Glad to help!

Comment: Wait, it looks like the question changed. I think I'd pretty much need the rest of your code! A possibility: is the activity registered in the manifest? Perhaps it'd be best to start a new stackoverflow question?

Answer (score 0):

have you not just tried using the Eclipse Template which set up everything for you just copy in your existing code?

File>New>Android Application Project then under the Create Activity Step select [image: see here:]

Comment: I can't user higher that 3.0(Honeycomb)

Comment: from memory the only bits that are honeycomb only are todo with the actionbar.. you should be able to remove or write your own implementation.. that said check out actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 0):

Your Fragment class needs an empty default constructor. See [Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#pubctors)